# Why contents inside php tags have issue inside index.php

Tags: php, html

There is some issue with the php code or the approach I am using to access contents of multiple pages, which results in failure of the display of contents inside index.php.

My index.php code logic is:

```
<div>
<ul>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=alta_usuari" title="Alta Usuaris">Alta Usuaris</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=gestio_usuaris" title="Gestio Usuaris">Gestio Usuaris</a></li>
      <

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentarea">
       <article id="article"><?php echo file_get_contents('pages/'. $pgname. '.php'); ?></article>
</div>
```

The code in on of the page is:

```
This text is displayed in main page after click on link
<?php
    echo "this text is not displayed after click on link. !";
?>
```

What is the issue in the approach I am using for accessing mulitple pages contents.
Is the issue is with:
`<article id="article"><?php echo file_get_contents('pages/'. $pgname. '.php'); ?></article>`

The complete code of index.php is:

```
<?php

// create an array with data for title, and meta, for each page

//TODO: pgdata from config file
$pgdata = array();
$pgdata['index'] = array(
  'title'=>' ',
  'description'=>'Here add the description for Home page',
  'keywords'=>'meta keywords, for, home page'
);
$pgdata['alta_usuari'] = array(
  'title'=>'Alta Usuari',
  'description'=>'Description for this page',
  'keywords'=>'alta usuari'
);
$pgdata['estat_hardware'] = array(
  'title'=>'Estat Hardware',
  'description'=>'Here add the description for the page',
  'keywords'=>'keyword 1,keyword 2'
);

// set the page name
//Then we set a variable with the name of the page. If there is $_GET['pg'],
// we get the name of the page from URL, otherwise we set the default name "index"; 
//and get its data from Array. 
$pgname = isset($_GET['pg']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['pg'])) : 'index';

// get title, and meta data for current /accessed page
$title = $pgdata[$pgname]['title'];
$description = $pgdata[$pgname]['description'];
$keywords = $pgdata[$pgname]['keywords'];

// set header for utf-8 encode

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
 <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style> <?php include 'css/main.css'; ?> </style>
 </head>

<body>

<header id="header">
 <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
</header>
<div id="line">
</div>
<div>
<ul>
     <!-- <li><a href="index.php" title="Alta Usuari">Alta Usuari</a></li> -->


      <li><a href="index.php?pg=alta_usuari" title="Alta Usuaris">Alta Usuaris</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=gestio_usuaris" title="Gestio Usuaris">Gestio Usuaris</a></li>

</div>

<div id="contentarea">
       <article id="article"> <?php echo include('pages/'. $pgname. '.php'); ?></article>
</div>


 <!--
<footer id="footer">
 <p>&copy air-fi.es</p>
</footer>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use include instead of file_get_contents

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't execute PHP code inside the file.

Comment: Yes, It worked, Thank You.

Comment: I followed a tutorial, Can you please explain how different page is loaded after clicking on the link. how the $pgname contents is updated after clicking on the link.

Comment: You haven't defined $pgname in your code sample above, so we can't tell you where it came from or how it gets changed. You'd have to add more code.

Comment: I updated the question by adding complete code.

Comment: Ok so `$pgname`'s value is determined by the value of `pg` in the GET parameters.  If there is no parameter set then it defaults to "index". This line controls it: `$pgname = isset($_GET['pg']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['pg'])) : 'index';`. In a HTTP GET request, the parameter values are taken from the querystring values (e.g. in your first hyperlink, you set `index.php?pg=alta_usuari` - so you set a parameter called "pg". When the user clicks the link, the browser requests this URL. The PHP script runs and `pg` is available to PHP in `$_GET['pg']` and then it can use that value as required.

Comment: So in the same example using your first hyperlink, when that link is clicked then the value inside `$_GET['pg']` (and thus `$pgname`, after it's assigned) will be "alta_usuari", because it takes it from the value in the URL. Does that make sense or do you need more?

Comment: Thank you, now I got it, how different pages are loaded on click. It is very very good explanation of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not execute php code as

> file_get_contents

is used. After replacing it with include, it successfully executed php code.

```
<div id="contentarea">
       <article id="article"> <?php echo include('pages/'. $pgname. '.php'); ?></article>
</div>
```

Thanks for the support.